# Does a PR card holder of Canada require transit visa in Amsterdam?

Tags: transit, canada

My daughter is a Permanent Resident of Canada. She is travelling from Moscow to Toronto, and with a return journey from Toronto to Moscow via Amsterdam (KLM flight) and will have a 6 hours layover at Amsterdam on the return journey, and on-board time 1:30hrs time to board for the Toronto flight.

Will she require a transit visa in Amsterdam?

Comment: Welcome to Travel Stack Exchange. When you write "Toranto", do you perhaps mean "Toronto"?

Comment: What is your daughter's citizenship?

Comment: What's a PR? I expect Permanent Resident? or is it for Public Relations of the Government of Canada?

Answer (score 3):

**No**, she won't need a transit visa. According to the Dutch embassy in [Moscow](http://rusland.nlambassade.org/shared/burgerzaken/burgerzaken%5B2%5D/visum---schengen/luchthaventransitvisum) (emphasis mine):

> Airport transit visa
>
> Whether you need a Schengen airport transit visa depends on your
>   nationality.
>
> You do not need Schengen airport transit visa if you:
>
> Hold a valid visa or a valid residence permit issued by a Schengen
>   country.
>   Hold a valid visa for a Member State of the European Union or the European Economic Area, Canada, Japan or the United States.
>   Have a valid residence permit issued by a Member State of the European Union or the European Economic Area.
>   **Have a residence permit issued by** the Principality of Andorra, **Canada**, Japan, San Marino or the United States guaranteeing an unlimited right of return.

Comment: You're using French rules for an Amsterdam layover. EU rules are indeed similar, but there are some differences country by country. I wouldn't trust the French rules and would look at Dutch ones instead.

Comment: @EugeneO updated

Comment: I would caution against this; as there is no such exception mentioned [at the official website of the Netherlands government](https://www.government.nl/topics/visa-for-the-netherlands-and-the-caribbean-parts-of-the-kingdom/question-and-answer/which-visa-do-i-need-to-travel-to-the-netherlands).